# "el" must exist in DOM when use backbone marionette in browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, browserify

I use the backbone marionette in browserify.

I met a problem about showing view.

I have `addRegions` and want to show the `ItemView`.

But the console show error: `Uncaught Error: An "el" #tmp_area must exist in DOM`.

My HTML file have `#tmp_area` area.

When I use require.js it doesn't show this problem, but it happened when I change to use browserify.

I don't know what's wrong.

Below is my code.

**app.js**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
Backbone.$ = $;

var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
var MyView = require('./views/my_view');

var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
    tmp_area: "#tmp_area"
});

app.addInitializer(function() {
    var myView = new MyView();
    app.tmp_area.show(myView);
});

app.on("initialize:after", function() {
    if (Backbone.history) {
        Backbone.history.start();
    }
});

app.start();
```

**my_view.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
var templates = require('../templates/tmp.hbs');
Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: templates,
})
```

Please help me!

I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is related to the document ready state. You can just put a script at the bottom of your HTML or wrap an application initialization step into [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Comment: Thank you!! It really fix it. But I am curious why it doesn't happen when I use require js.

Comment: @JackHou You've probably used `data-main` attribute of the require script to define the main file, right? RequireJS loads this main file asynchronously, that's why document was ready at the time RequireJS has fetched it.